# Is it possible to view my gross margin (revenue minus ad expenses) on appannie.com?

Tags: analytics

I'm interested in seeing how my ads effect sales but that difficult to do when the revenue chart doesn't have the ad expenses subtracted from it.  In other words, I would like to see my income after subtracting my ad expenses.  Appannie already has the data from both my ad expenses and of course my revenue and they send out a daily email with the Gross Margin but is it possible to plot the Gross Margin on their site?

Comment: It seems to me that this is a more appropriate question for [webmasters.se].

Comment: But I'm not asking how to build this feature, I'm asking if it exists in this web application and how to use it.

Comment: True, and perhaps it is okay here. But Webmasters has a slightly different focus than this site. I think you'll get better answers there.